# couldn't find DSO to load: "libhermes-executor-release.so" caused by: com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor

Tags: android, react-native

[React-Native] - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-release.so caused by: com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor result: 0

This is not a duplicate question,

I get this error when I try to open my application on Android 11.
It opens fine on other android versions.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-release.so caused by: com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor result: 0
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a(:7)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a(Unknown Source:104)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a(:13)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a(Unknown Source:1)
        at e.d.k.b.a.<clinit>(Unknown Source:17)
        at e.d.k.b.b.create(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(Unknown Source:58)
```

Emphasis on this `libhermes-executor-release.so caused by: com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor`

I have hermes enabled, I also have proguard enabled. I have done literally all the solutions that I have seen on github and stackoverflow.

I TRIED THE FOLLOWING

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.2"
    }
}
```

```
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
    }
```

I also ran ./gradlew clean multiple times but nothing happened.

When I turn off Hermes, it works fine.

React-Native Version - 0.63.4
Android 11

Answer (score 0):

Try to add react native version to your android/build.gradle.
You can use specific version:

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = "0.63.4"
```

Or get it from your package.json:

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

  allprojects {
      configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy {
              force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
          }
      }
      repositories  { ... }
```

Comment: Anyone got a solution for this? I'm having the same issue